# Adding Delay and ADSR filter using Processing Minim Library

Tags: audio, processing, minim

Here is my Processing code. If someone can show me how to add either a Delay or ADSR filter (or both) to it's output that would be great.

```java
Minim minim;
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;



AudioOutput out_1;
Delay myDelay1;
SineWave sine_1;
float freq_1 = 82;



void setup() 
{
minim = new Minim(this);
out_1 = minim.getLineOut(Minim.STEREO);

sine_1 = new SineWave(440, 0.5, out_1.sampleRate());


int port = 10;

sine_1.portamento(port);

out_1.addSignal(sine_1);


}


void draw() 
{

   background(240);
   freq_1 = 1169.25;   
   sine_1.setFreq(freq_1);
}

void stop()
{
out_1.close();
minim.stop();
super.stop();
}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question to the Processing forum and got a good answer [here](http://forum.processing.org/topic/adding-delay-and-adsr-filter-using-processing-minim-library).